# Sending Commands to a Running Eclipse Instance

Tags: eclipse, external

We're planning to build a custom visualizer for a the Orx game engine, and the intention is to be able to click on an object in the visualizer and jump to the .cpp source file of the object in an external editor. I know that some editors listen to a socket for these kinds of commands (like open file), does Eclipse also have such a network interface? I've tried googling and also checking Eclipse's documentation with no luck.

Comment: Eclipse does not have anything like this.

Comment: @greg-449 So, then, one needs an Eclipse plugin to achieve that?

Comment: Yes, you could do it with a plug-in. But moving to the correct place in the editor is probably going to need a lot of knowledge of the Eclipse C++ editor.

Comment: @greg-449 Why couldn't one just say go to line 67 in file someobject.cpp? Isn't there a generic API for text editors? (Note that I assume I already know the file name and the line number without Eclipse's help)

Comment: If that is all you want to do that is straightforward

Comment: Thanks, I guess a plugin is the way to go then.

Comment: @enobayram by the way, if you go for such a plugin and implement a relatively frequent protocol, you should consider contributing it to Eclipse.org so it has chances to get into mainstream Eclipse IDE one day.

Comment: @Mickael Sure, I'll try to do that

Comment: You can also use a command-line to directly open a file in Eclipse, but it doesn't allow to specify a line number as far as I know: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/OpenFileFeature . If this is what you need, consider reporting an enhancement request to http://bugs.eclipse.org

Comment: @Mickael Nice, this seems to get half of the job done, and it's the bigger half :)